# Renaming regex returned token values and passing old token value(before they were renamed) to a drilldown search query in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

I've a splunk query that finds top errors in the log using regular expression. I then display it as a bar chart. the regex returns 10 values for error.

```
someSearchQuery
| rex "someTerm(?<error>)
| stats count by error
| sort - count 
| head 10
```

I want to use the values returned by the query in a drilldown such that clicking on a barchart will display results for that value

The drilldown xml I used for setting token is this

```
<drilldown> 
    <set token="show_panel">true</set>
    <set token="selected_value">$click.value$</set>
</drilldown>
```

and then I use this token in the drilldown query as such

```
someSearchQuery
| rex "someTerm(?<error>)
| search error=$selected_value$
| timechart count by errorType span="1m"
| addcoltotals
| rename NULL as count
```

These error names are too technical and I want to change them to something general in the main panel and drilldown both.

for example, if regex returned error "ID not found", I want to replace it with "Data_error"

Also I want my title to change with the general name

```
<title>$selected_value$</title>
```

But the problem is when I change the name using `eval`, the drilldown query doesn't get the actual error name and search fails because there is no such error as "Data_error". The query needs "ID not found" to function.

Is there any way this can be achieved? Can I change the name of my searchTerm and at the same time use the old searchTerm in drilldown query as well?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out. Putting it out there for the community(I had help from other developers):
Steps-->

1.Set an additional token in the drildown. use an eval rather than set

```
<drilldown>
        <set token="show_panel">true</set>
        <set token="selected_value">$click.value$</set>
        <eval token="converted_value">case($click.value$="ID not found","Data_error",$click.value$="some other code","some other value")</eval>
   </drilldown>
```

2.Change the names with an eval in the search as done before, then change it back in the drilldown eval.